# How to access the `browser` object in JavaScript (or TypeScript, or Dart)

Tags: javascript, typescript, dart, dom

There are some APIs which are still a bit mysterious to me. I'm not really sure if they represent a compatibility problem, but often I find tutorials online where they can access these variables/objects by default, and I simply cannot reproduce them locally, even after trying it on different browsers, environments and languages.

One of these is the `browser` variable. When and how can I access it?

For example, [MDN's `manifest.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands) documentation shows a very simple way for an extension to access typed shortcuts from the browser:

```js
browser.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
  if (command === "toggle-feature") {
    console.log("Toggling the feature!");
  }
});
```

It even shows an example [here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/commands).

But I just can't access this `browser` variable/object anywhere. I've tried, with no success, doing so through JS, TS, Dart, both in website and extension environments; and the browser console on Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Firefox. How and when can I access it? — the `chrome` variable is also another one that seems inconsistent to me, sometimes I can access it, sometimes I simply cannot.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: The browser object is only available when you develop a **brower extension**, not a **web application**. Therefore, what you ask for is not possible (access browser object from web page).

The longer answer is that the availability of infrastructure depends on the execution context: Is it a web page? Is it an extension? Or Javascript running on a server? Firefox? Chrome? etc. Unfortunately, lots of information on the internet assumes that it is "obvious" which execution context they are referring to.

In Chrome you have access to the chrome object on a web page. (you can check this on the console). Maybe that helps in your situation?

Last, regarding compatibility. Check out libraries like [webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) that unify behavior across browsers. But again, this only helps with browser extensions, not web applications.